# firebug 1.9.1 in Firefox 11 debugger not working

Tags: firebug

When I activate script panel it says "Debugger not activated", but i cant make firebug break at debugger; or at a break point.

I have reinstalled the plugin.
Reset it to default settings.
Deleted the firefox profile
Reboot computer

Nothing works, This version have been working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reinstalled firefox and firebug, and now it works again..

Comment: Another thing to check is that you do not have any waiting prompts, alerts, or confirm boxes open in other tabs or windows as that will cause the same error message to appear!

Comment: It is ridiculous that this is necessary

Answer (score 4):

Same thing happened to me (FF 18; FB 1.11.1).  Some Googling found [this](http://markmail.org/message/mde4fe7ctazi4ejo#query:+page:1+mid:mde4fe7ctazi4ejo+state:results) which fixed my problem:

> The same problem happened to me recently. I've cleared cache and
>   cookies and it worked fine. Not sure, probably clearing cache only
>   will be enough. In Firefox choose Tools -> Clear Recent Hisotry ->
>   Cache(checkbox) Reload the page or restart Firefox and it should work
>   fine.

Answer (score 1):

Firebug version only supported to related Firefox version. so install firebug to related firefox version.

For Example.
    Firefox 3.6 with Firebug 1.7.3

```
Firefox 4.0 with Firebug 1.7.3

Firefox 5.0 with Firebug 1.8.2 (and also Firebug 1.7.3)

Firefox 6.0 with Firebug 1.8.2 (and also Firebug 1.9)

Firefox 7.0 with Firebug 1.8.2 (and also Firebug 1.9)

Firefox 8.0 with Firebug 1.8.3 (and also Firebug 1.9)

Firefox 9.0 with Firebug 1.8.4 (and also Firebug 1.9)

Firefox 10.0 with Firebug 1.9

Firefox 11.0 with Firebug 1.9

Firefox 12.0 with Firebug 1.9

Firefox 13.0 with Firebug 1.10 (and also Firebug 1.9)

Firefox 14.0 with Firebug 1.10

Firefox 15.0 with Firebug 1.10

Firefox 16.0 with Firebug 1.10

Firefox 17.0 with Firebug 1.11 (and also Firebug 1.10)

Firefox 18.0 with Firebug 1.11

Firefox 19.0 with Firebug 1.11

Firefox 20.0 with Firebug 1.11

Firefox 21.0 with Firebug 1.11

Firefox 22.0 with Firebug 1.11

Firefox 23.0 with Firebug 1.12 (and also Firebug 1.11)

Firefox 24.0 with Firebug 1.12

Firefox 25.0 with Firebug 1.12
```

[See this Link I think it will helpfull to you.](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/?src=dp-dl-dependencies)

Answer (score 0):

I has similar issue with FireFox 7.0.1. Got it solved by re-installing FireBug. Now its working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

OP said this didn't work for them but before you go to the trouble of reinstalling, try this certified "Works on My Machine" fix:

In the Firebug pane, click the "Firebug" menu icon.

Under the options menu, select "Reset all Firebug options."

Answer (score 0):

Check for Javascript debugger, Due to adding this addon firebug debugging will be disabled. Disabling Javascript debugger will active firebug debugging again

Answer (score 0):

In my case id did not work in Firefox (Ubuntu), because I had to:

- Enable Net tab
- Enable Script tab