# MVC4 jQuery UI does not work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ui-datepicker

I cannot get jQuery UI working in my ASP.NET MVC4 application. I tried dialog and datepicker.
Here is part of the code of my view.

```
<link href="../../Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert('A');
    //$('#datepicker').val('test');
    $('#datepicker').datepicker();
    alert('B');
});
</script>
<h1>Test</h1>
<form id="testForm" action="#" method="get">
    <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="datepicker" class="datepicker" />
</form>
```

The alert A is displayed. When I uncomment the next row, the value test is assigned. But datepicker is not working and alert B does not display.

Thanks,
Petr

Comment: Are there any errors in the console (Chrome dev toolbar, Firebug etc?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the layout.cshtml view, move

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

from body to head and add in head too

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
```

Comment: No, you will need to add the css as well with this:@Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")

Answer (score 4):

I spent lots of time to figure out how to make it working.

Finally the steps are following:

1. Create ASP .NET MVC4 project Internet Application.
2. Clean some of the last lines of the `_Layout.cshtml` so it should look like this

   ```
   <footer>
           <div class="content-wrapper">
               <div class="float-left">
                   <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET MVC Application</p>
               </div>
           </div>
       </footer>

       @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
   ```
3. Change header like I did here

> ```
>  <head>
>         <meta charset="utf-8" />
>         <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title>
>         <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
>         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
>         @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
>         @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
>         @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
>         @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
>         @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
>         <script type="text/javascript">
>             $(document).ready(function () {
>                 // We will test DataPicker
>                 $('#datep').datepicker();
>                 // We will test TABS
>                 $(function () {
>                     $("#tabs").tabs();
>                 });
>             });
>         </script>
>     </head>
> ```

4. Delete all code after `@section featured {` section and add some html to `Home/Index.cshtml`

   A. Put some code from the ***view source*** link of  http://jqueryui.com/tabs/ page (It is inside of `< div id="tabs" > ...  < div >`)

   B. Add this

> < div >
>               Date: < input id="datep" type="text" / >
>           < / div >

DONE!!!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your code runs just fine in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m3QFL/

Check the console for errors and the path to your scripts. Chrome includes a console to help with js debugging or you can run FireFox and [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/).

Either one will go a long way in helping you solve issues like this.

Also, hosted versions of jquery and jquery ui are available through jquery and jquery ui or Google. Here are yours:

`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>`

[jquery ui](http://api.jqueryui.com/) has links at the bottom of their homepage to their hosted versions.

BTW, the `//` instead of `http://` allows the script to pick up the `http` prefix from the site. If you are on ssl it will pick up the `https://` so you don't have secure and non-secure items on your page.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer. I tried the googleapis scripts, with the same result. When I set breakpoints in FireBug on all three lines, the first one is hit, then the alert A appears, then the page is loaded and the debuger shows "debugger not activated".

Comment: @Petr That's an issue with the Firebug install: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9990906/firebug-1-9-1-in-firefox-11-debugger-not-working

Answer (score 2):

You will need to add a couple lines to your _Layout.cshtml to get jQuery UI working out of the box.  First is the javascript bundle:

```
@*you should already have this line*@
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

@*add this line*@
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
```

Next you need the CSS for jQuery UI as well:

```
@*you should already have this line*@
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")

@*add this line*@
@Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
```