# How to get a JavaScript date picker working

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, webforms, datepicker

I have an asp.net website and I'm trying to add a date picker but I can't seem to get it working. I have tried every answer on this website and I still get the "*object doesn't support property or method 'datepicker'*" error message when I try and debug it.

I have watched [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tkKrvgANv8A) and I have copied step by step and still get the error. What can I try to get it working?  I have no code at all as I undid all my solutions.

I even tried [this website](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) but still it didn't work.  Why is it so hard to get working?

I want an input field with the calendar at the end.

Comment: It's gonna be impossible for us to troubleshoot your problem if you have _no code at all_. Why don't you write some code, post it here and show us the problem?

Comment: I struggled with Bootstrap and jQuery for tabs and datepicker for a while not long ago.  For me it came down to the the load order of scripts and ScriptReference entries in the ScriptManager element.  For example, I added scripts for jQuery UI, and datepicker wouldn't work until I removed the asp:ScriptReference element for jQuery that VS put there automatically.

Comment: @TonyHinkle So you completely removed `                    <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />` from the `<Scripts>` then?

Comment: That is what I had to do to fix at least one thing.  If you've added in your own script references for bootstrap and/or jquery, you may need to remove the asp:ScriptReference items.  Easy to test--just remove it and rebuild and see if it works.  Also, use F12 in Chrome or Firebug in Firefox to see if it is getting any errors finding the scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer in this post by jk: [MVC4 jQuery UI does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13112519/mvc4-jquery-ui-does-not-work).

All I did was add the script they mentioned below my `<asp:ScriptManager runat="server">` section and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In the above video it's using jquery datetime picker.I think you are using both bootstrap and jquery date time picker inside your project it also contain the datetime picker.Remove one of them in your project and check it again..